# Lua Changing Table Keys

Tags: lua, lua-table, array-key

Anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
GET_TABLE {1=ID}
key = string.format("%q", GET_TABLE[1])
RETURN_TABLE[key] = "ss"
print(RETURN_TABLE[ID])
print(GET_TABLE[1])
```

First `print` result: `nil`. Second `print` result: `ID`

I want the first `print` result to be: `ss`

```
GET_TABLE {1=ID}
key = "ID"
RETURN_TABLE[key] = "ss"
print(RETURN_TABLE[ID])
print(GET_TABLE[1])
```

The above works fine so I assume its due to the `string.format` not working right?

Comment: Why don't you print the result of the string.format so you can see what you are getting, then fix it?

Comment: `GET_TABLE {1=ID}` <-- This calls the function `GET_TABLE()` with the given table literal as the only argument.  Are you missing an equals sign, or are you really calling a function and then trying to index it?

Comment: By the way, in Lua a table key can be of *any* type except `nil`, so the `format` may not be necessary for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%q` format token returns the input as an escaped and quoted Lua string.  This means that given the input `ID` it will return `"ID"` (the double quotes being part of the string!) which is a different string.  (Or, represented as Lua strings, the input is `'ID'` and the return value is `'"ID"'`.)

You have therefore set the `ID` key while trying to retrieve the `"ID"` key (which presumably does not exist).

```
> x = 'ID'
> =x
ID
> =string.format('%q', x)
"ID"
> =#x
2
> =#string.format('%q', x)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile (you need [] around the index), and you should use the raw string of ID, not the "quoted" string:

```
GET_TABLE = {[1]=ID}
key = string.format("%s", GET_TABLE[1])
```

Note that I had to initialize ID and RETURN_TABLE objects to the following:

```
ID = 'ID'
RETURN_TABLE = {}
```

Stylistic note: you should only use all-caps names for constants, otherwise too many makes code hard to read